# Comando SQL para somar as vagas ocupadas em um dia específico de um estacionamento

Tags: sql, sql-server

Fala pessoal, estou com um pequeno problema pra terminar um trabalho da faculdade e seria de grande ajuda se vocês me ajudassem com uma pequena VIEW.

Aqui tem os campos da tabela estacionamento:

```
CREATE TABLE Seg.Estacionamento (
valor_hora decimal(4,2),
numero_vagas integer,
hora_saida datetime,
hora_entrada datetime,
vaga varchar(6)
)
```

Essa tabela registra cada entrada no estacionamento.

É o seguinte, estou fazendo um projeto de banco de dados para um shopping center e preciso fazer um relatório de vagas ocupadas por dia no estacionamento do shopping center.

Ficaria alguma coisa assim

```
Quantidade de Vagas | Data
                    |
                    |
                    |
```

O campo Quantidade de Vagas é o somatório de todas as vagas da data em questão e a Data tem de ser dia-a-dia. Mas eu não tenho ideia de como escrever essa VIEW, o que eu tentei até agora foi algo assim, mas eu sei que está completamente errado:

```
CREATE VIEW v_Vagas
AS
SELECT SUM(E.vaga) as "Quantidade de vagas ocupadas" FROM Estacionamento AS E
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT DAY(E.hora_entrada))
```

Por favor me ajudem, é muito importante

Comment: Bom, tem algumas coisas que ficam em aberto na sua pergunta. Por exemplo, uma vaga que foi ocupada e desocupada 3 vezes durante o dia conta como 1 ou como 3?

Comment: O relatório não seria "de _número máximo_ de vagas ocupadas por dia"? Ou o que se deseja saber é quais vagas foram ocupadas em cada dia? // O que contém a coluna `vaga`?

Answer (score 0):

Julgando pela view que você tentou criar, o script abaixo vai te trazer quantas vagas foram ocupadas em um determinado dia. Note que seu campo "hora_entrada" é um DATETIME, então iremos selecionar apenas a informação da data com o CAST().

```
CREATE VIEW v_Vagas
AS

    SELECT SUM(CAST(E.vaga AS INT)) AS 'Quantidade de vagas ocupadas', CAST(hora_entrada AS DATE) AS 'Data'
    FROM Estacionamento AS E
    GROUP BY CAST(hora_entrada AS DATE)

GO
```

Entretanto, se o objetivo é apenas saber quantos carros estacionaram durante o dia, podemos contar quantas linhas "hora_entrada" existem no mesmo dia, sem precisar do campo "vaga".

```
CREATE VIEW v_Vagas
AS

    SELECT COUNT(hora_entrada) AS 'Quantidade de vagas ocupadas',
        CAST(hora_entrada AS DATE) AS 'Data'
    FROM Estacionamento AS E
    GROUP BY CAST(hora_entrada AS DATE)

GO
```

Comment: Poderia explicar sua resposta?